(Mac user) Found old Multibit.key file and have installed Classic. I have imported the key and it is now syncing... what next?
From searching around I have managed to install MultiBit classic and amended the java file so it would work.
Imported the key and I think entered the password correctly, it now says:
importing private keys...completed successfully
And the wallet is now synchronising. I imagine this could take a few days?
After this, do I need to install Multibit HD? What is the process from here?
Thank you!


What is the process from here?

According to https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit

Videos that demonstrate how to move your wallet to Electrum are available on YouTube.

But, like Multibit itself, the links are defunct, so
See
MultiBit with multiple addresses to Electrum and answers to other questions about Multibit and Electrum

Those videos no longer work

@Zaq answer updated

Multibit classic has a lot of bugs and is now outdated and discontinued. It will be better and much more safe to import your private keys into electrum wallet
